# Static Analyzer Xcode 4.3.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Im really having a problem with determining locations of my leaks, my client detected it via `TARGETS > RUN STATIC ANALYZER` and set to YES. And then in `Product` click `Analyze`

He was able to see something like this:

[image]

But in mine I wasn't able to output the same as above. Tried searching in the internet, but there weren't working. Am I missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If `self.responseData` a `retain` property?

Comment: My first guess would be that you're using `ARC` and he isn't.

Comment: The image above are just examples.

Comment: @NJones, I was able to detect the memory leaks via intruments, but I think the image above is a little bit easy, just saying.

Comment: ....Then you've given us basically zero information.  The answer is "Because your client's build environment is different than yours"

Comment: @borrrden does it matter if hes using snow leopard and im using lion?

Comment: That could indicate that you have different versions of Xcode.  Snow Leopard only supports up to 4.2.  So unless you are running 4.2, your Xcodes are different.

Comment: @borrrden so its possible that he has leaks on my code and mine doesnt have?

Comment: Doubtful...you are just using different versions of the static analyzer in that case (the newer ones are more accurate).  Note the word "potential" (check to see if you actually do leak it using instruments, or just by looking at the code in question).

Answer (score 0):

```
self.responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:[data length]];
```

This creates and initializes an object. Therefore, that function owns that object. If you are using your properties properly, it will either be retained when assigned (in that statement), and released when that field is reassigned (declared `retain`), or copied and the copy will be released appropriately (`copy`).  Either of these leaves the object with a retain count of 1 and no pointers to it, the definition of a leak.  You need to `release` or `autorelease` that object somewhere in that function.

```
self.responseData = [[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:[data length]] autorelease];
```

or

```
NSMutableData *newData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:[data length]];
self.responseData = newData;
[newData release];
```

Comment: does it matter if hes using snow leopard and im using lion?